# How to add a timer in webforms application to track the time user spent on website

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web forms application that has many aspx pages. I need to track the time that passed after the user has logged in and raise event after 30 seconds.

The problem is I have no idea how to make it track the time on multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate GUID for each page visit and store it in a hidden field in the master page and use javascript timer to update visit time on the server by using API call (Web method)

you will use the GUID to call the web method